# Find the equivalence classes of $[(0,0)],[(1,0)],[\left(\sqrt2,0\right)]$ and $[(0,-2)]$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

On the set  $\mathbb{R}^2$, define $(x,y) R (a,b)$ if and only if $x^2-y =a^2-b$. Find the equivalence classes of $[(0,0)],[(1,0)],[\left(\sqrt2,0\right)]$ and $[(0,-2)] $and  give a geometric description of them.

---

**$[(0,0)]=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:(x,y)R(0,0)\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2-y=0\}$**

**$[(1,0)]=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:(x,y)R(1,0)\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2-y=1\}$**

**$[(0,1)]=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:(x,y)R(0,1)\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2-y=-1\}$**

**$[(\sqrt2,0)]=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:(x,y)R(\sqrt2,0)\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2-y=2\}$**

**$[(0,2)]=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:(x,y)R(0,2)\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x^2-y=-2\}$**

**Geometric description:**  parabolas of the form $y=x^2-a^2+b$

Is  my work correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your working is fine.

The equivalence class of $[(a,b)]$ is the parabolas of the form of $y=x^2-a^2+b$ where $-a^2+b$ is the intercept term.

Comment: Thank you so much Siong, and how can I construct a bijection between the quotient set and $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Find the representation $[(a,b)]=[(0,r)]$. Geometrically well, just use the intercept to define the bijection.